# Waveshare touch screen driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have Waveshare 7" touchscreen with me. I have interface it to my desktop machine running Ubuntu 16.04. I have successfully set the custom resolution of using cvt and xrandr command in Ubuntu. I am happy with the screen resolution.

Now my next task is to get the touchscreen working with Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed the touchscreen driver from github from the below link
https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver
But no success. I have even tried the touchscreen driver written in C from the below link.
https://github.com/110yd/wshare-touchscreen
But still no success.

Can anyone show me the way to implement touchscreen driver with X server support?